# Charged particle in uniform electro-magnetic field - what is $\omega$?

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity

Let $\mathbf{E}$ || $\mathbf{B}$ and $\mathbf{E}=E\mathbf{e}_z$ and let the charge of the particle (rest mass $m_0$) be $e$.
The relativistic equations of motion are:

$$\dot{u}^0=\frac{eE}{m_0c}u^3=\omega_Eu^3\\
\dot{u}^1=\frac{eB}{m_0}u^2=\omega_Bu^2\\
\dot{u}^2=-\frac{eB}{m_0}u^1=-\omega_Bu^1\\
\dot{u}^3=\frac{eE}{m_0c}u^0=\omega_Eu^0$$

BTW I'm not a physicist, but that's fine. I was just wondering how the angular frequencies $\omega_E$ and $\omega_B$ are called?

I know, this is somehow a stupid question, don't know how to google for these sort of questions.There should be a search engine for common formulas...

Comment: Are you sure those are the relativistic equation of motion?  I don't see those topic since a lot so I may be wrong but I think $\omega_B$ is the non relativistic Larmor frequency. You can find it in any text talking about synchrotron radiation. I think Jackson 's electrodynamics has a chapter about that. "Ribicky - Lightman radiative processes in astrophysics"  surely talks about that aswell as Padmanabhan 's book on radiative processes. Sorry I can't provide link now, maybe later I'll make a new comment with links. Look for the Larmor frequency anyway,  that should be the answer

Comment: Thx for your response. Yes, I'm pretty sure as I just copied them from a SRT textbook, $u^\mu$ is the four-velocity, i.e. the $\mu$ superscripts represent the $\mu$'th component of the four-vector (not the power). Anyway, are you sure that both $\omega_E$ and $\omega_B$ is called Larmor-frequency?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the Larmor frequency for the electron is $\omega_L=qb/(mc)$ and the relativistic one is $\omega_{L \, rel} = (1/\gamma) \omega_L$, where $\gamma$ is the Lorentz factor.Be careful, in my formulae there's a c because I use cgs units, you don't have that c cause you have SI units,  but that's still the Larmor frequency

Comment: No, just $\omega_B$ is the Larmor one, I have no idea about the other since I never studied the motion with the Electric field on, cause in astrophysics(where I come from)  electric fields are usually negligible

Comment: ok, thx for that hint.